# How start pdb on exception for asyncio code

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pdb

I'm having an asyncio application, where some exceptions occur.

Let's for example take this small script:

```
import asyncio

async def coro1():
    for a in range(1, -1, -1):
       await asyncio.sleep(1)
       print("coro1", a)
       c = 1/a  # ### !!!Will raise exception when a is 0!!!!

async def coro2():
    for n in range(6):
        print("------- coro2", n)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main():
    coros = [coro1(), coro2()]
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coros)
    print("comp", completed)
    print("pend", pending)

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
event_loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

If I had similar problems with a single threaded non asyncio program I would just do

```
python -m pydb scriptname
```

type `c` and end up with pydb at the code, that provoked the exception now I could view and display variables and I could see for example, that `a` was 0

I tried the same with my asyncio application,

and I receive the exception only after coro2 finished and pdb does not stop when the error occurs.

I am aware that entering into pdb will block the whole asyncio event loop, but this is just for a postmortem analysis, so it wouldn't be an issue.

If entering pdb is not working, then I'd be curious how others debug such issues. 
Is there anything smarter, then adding prints and logs after the error occurred and hoping the error will occur again?

Here the output of my above script when started with `python -m pdb`

```
(gelonida) gelonida@host:~/work/so/asynciopdb$ python -m pdb ./corodbg.py
[2] > /home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py(2)<module>()
-> import asyncio
(Pdb++) c
---- coro2 0
---- coro2 1
coro1 1
---- coro2 2
---- coro2 3
coro1 0
---- coro2 4
---- coro2 5
comp {<Task finished coro=<coro2() done, defined at /home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py:10> result=None>, <Task finished coro=<coro1() done, defined at /home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py:4> exception=ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)>}
pend set()
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<coro1() done, defined at /home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py:4> exception=ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py", line 8, in coro1
    c = 1/a
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
The program finished and will be restarted
[2] > /home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py(2)<module>()
-> import asyncio
(Pdb++)
```

I'm having pdbpp installed, but the same happens without pdbpp

**Addendum:**
I saw, that I can add one of the following params to `asyncio.wait()`

`return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION`

or

`return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`

This would allow me to not continue the other coroutines if an exception occurred.
On the other hand I still don't know how to enter pdb and access the back trace of the failed coroutine.

**Addendum 2:**
I also found that I can add an exception handler to asyncio But also this handler seems to be called a little too late.
I did following:

```
def act_pdb(loop, context):
    print("EXC", loop, context)
    pdb.set_trace()
    loop.default_exception_handler(context)

event_loop.set_exception_handler(act_pdb)
```

combined with `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`
pdb will be activated after the exception occurred and before the other coroutine finished. but I do not know whether it is still possible to move me to the back trace of the failed coro or whether the coro is already destroyed.

The backtrace I get is:

```
[0]   /home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py(34)<module>()
-> loop.run_until_complete(main())
[1]   /home/gelonida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py(454)run_until_complete()
-> self.run_forever()
[2]   /home/gelonida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py(421)run_forever()
-> self._run_once()
[3]   /home/gelonida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py(1431)_run_once()
-> handle._run()
[4]   /home/gelonida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py(145)_run()
-> self._callback(*self._args)
[5]   /home/gelonida/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py(1299)call_exception_handler()
-> self._exception_handler(self, context)
[6] > /home/gelonida/work/so/asynciopdb/corodbg.py(30)bla()
-> loop.default_exception_handler(context)
```

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue32900

Comment: Also, try `loop.set_debug(True)` https://devdocs.io/python~3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop#enabling-debug-mode

Comment: @hjpotter92 thks 4 the link. Looks interesting if I  wanted to  step through an asyncio app. It says its tough to step through asyncio apps as one steps mostly through asyncio internals instead of  ones own code.

It suggests to do something like 
`pdb.Pdb(skip={"trio", "contextlib", ...}).run(...)` to simplify stepping.

However In my context I enter pdb only after an error occurred, so I can't step anymore; Only thing I could do is to examine the back trace and variables. But I don't know how to enter the scope of a coroutine (if it still exists at the moment pdb kicks in)

Comment: also added loop.set_debug(True)

Still getting the same back trace and don't know how I could enter the scope of my coroutine in order to display for example the contents of the variable a.

In the moment I'm stuck to look at the back trace, manually add  pdb.set_trace(), rerun the code and step from then on through the code till the error occur.
Here the link that you posted might help. have to understand though how to activate 
`pdb.Pdb(skip={"trio", "contextlib", ...})` I'm still not completely sure how I would do that in my context